# Como usar o zipalign no Andriod Studio?

Tags: android

Trabalho com o android studio no mac, e no momento gero o app com o zipalign que vem junto a ide utilizando comando via terminal. Toda vez que gero o app mostra essa mensagem da imagem, existe a possibilidade de configurar automaticamente na IDE?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Tente copiar o `zipalign` da pasta `android-studio\sdk\build-tools\20.0.0\` para `android-studio\sdk\tools\`, houve uma migração recente (antes ele ficava nessa pasta `\sdk\tools`) e me parece que não foi alterado nas `IDE's`

Comment: Funcionou, colocar sua dica como resposta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basta copiar o `zipalign` da pasta `android-studio\sdk\build-tools\versao_do_seu_build` para `android-studio\sdk\tools`.

Houve uma migração recente no SDK (antes ele ficava nessa pasta `...\sdk\tools`) e me parece que não foi alterado nas IDE's

Comment: Muito bom, funcionou aqui